# .dateParseExact return null

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to parse the following date:

> Tue, 27 Oct 2015 00:00:00 GMT

this is my code:

```
start = Date.parse(currDateStart.toString('dd/MM/yyyy') 
                                            + ' ' + workingDay.start, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
```

where currDateStart is the date that I want parse (see above), and `working.start` contains : `09:00` so the final result should be:

> Tue, 27 Oct 2015 09:00:00 GMT

but instead I get `null` why?

Comment: I'm using momentjs. NB: I've no problem in toString(), infact  the date returned is the same above when I do: Tue, 27 Oct 2015 00:00:00 GMT

Answer (score 0):

Neither `moment` or `Date` will accept a format parameter in the `toString` function.

Assuming `curreDateStart` and the output `start` are both `moment` objects, then you should do this:

```
start = moment(currDateStart.format("YYYY-MM-DD") + ' ' + workingDay.start);
```

If you wanted `Date` or `string` output, you could call `toDate` or `format` from there.

If the input is something besides a `moment` object, then create a `moment` object from it first, such as `moment(currentDateStart)` if it's a `Date`, or `moment.utc(currentDateStart, "ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss")` if its a `string` in GMT.