# currDateStart.format is not a function

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to parse this date `Tue, 27 Oct 2015 00:00:00 GMT` (is a string). For parse the date I'm using this solution:

```
start = moment(currDateStart.format("YYYY-MM-DD") + ' ' + workingDay.start);
```

where `currDateStart` is the date above and `workingDay.start` correpond to `09:00`.

So the final result should be like this: `Tue, 27 Oct 2015 09:00:00 GMT`

But my problem's that I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: currDateStart.format is not a function

I'm using `moment.js` what's the problem?

Comment: Looks like you were taking code from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33353419/634824) - where I specifically stated that I was assuming `currDateStart` was a `moment` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to close your parenthesis earlier:

```
start = moment(currDateStart).format("YYYY-MM-DD") + ' ' + workingDay.start;
```

so that you are calling `format` on a `moment` object.

http://jsfiddle.net/FLhpq/2218/

or

http://jsfiddle.net/FLhpq/2219/

Comment: Okay, now the code working, the only problem is that I lost the format, infact the ouput is like this: 2015-10-26 09:00 instead of this: Tue, 27 Oct 2015 09:00:00 GMT

Comment: start = moment(moment("Tue, 27 Oct 2015 00:00:00 GMT").format("YYYY-MM-DD") + ' ' + workingDay.start).toString();

Comment: Okay but the jsfiddle are equal

Comment: Also the date returned by your code is in italian language and the currDateStart is in english, there is a way to get all date in english?

Comment: @InTim3 - if you're using `moment`, you should not be using `toString`, but rather `format`, with all of the various options available to it.

Comment: Okay I've solved using .lang method. I've another question: if workingDay.start is equal to 18:00 the final date of your code display: Tue, 27 Oct 2015 06:00:00 GMT instead of Tue, 27 Oct 2015 18:00:00 GMT, how I can fix this?